# Trouble finding where SQL table prefix is being called

Tags: php, wordpress

Recently took over a website for an old friend who said they had a bad developer, nonprofit for an rare illness

There's a page on the website they use to search physicians who know how to treat the disease that stopped working shortly after they moved to another server, basically you throw in your zip code and it gives you a range

Using web console I was able to find it giving a 500 error

The script is trying to call for a table that exists in SQL on the server but had a prefix renamed from "website_" (on the old server) to "wp_" (on the new server)

I'm having issues finding what script is calling the "website_" instead of the "wp_" prefix, and not entirely sure where I could look if anyone is able to give advice on where I could

Webconsole listed a .js file in the /assets folder of the theme files however searching the .js file I found no "website_" prefix calling in the code

Comment: It's unlikely that the problem is with the JavaScript code, more likely PHP. The database prefix will either be set in the main WordPress configuration file or else it might be defined in the plugin code for the search facility - by this I mean that the ZIP code search might have been implemented using a custom plug-in, therefore the settings in the plugin code might not match what is in the WordPress configuration file.

Comment: Just to add, if you have a good text editor application you can usually run "find" on whole directories, not just the files you have open in the text editor, which should quickly find any scripts that are using the wrong prefix.